# Seems like it is not reading the list and my loop is not working

Tags: python, list, dictionary, checkout

I have to call the readPriceList function to read the price list from a text file and display it. Then I have to use a loop for the customer to enter the product code. When he enter the code that is not on the list, display item not found. Otherwise, item found and the price. And 9999 to exit the loop.

```
def scanPrices():
    price_list = readPriceList()
    price = set(price_list)
    itemCode = 0
    totalPrice = 0.0
    item_price = price_list.values()
    itemCode = int(input("Enter 4-digit item code [or 9999 to stop]: "))
    while itemCode != 9999:
        itemCode = int(input("Enter 4-digit item code [or 9999 to stop]: "))
        if itemCode in price_list:
            itemPrice = price_list.values()
            print("Item found. Price:", item_price)
        else:
            print("Item not found")
    return totalPrice
```

This is my output:

```
Welcome to Wake-Mart. Please register!
Name: lol
Enter credit card number: 444444
Enter security code: 454
Enter debit card number: 44444444
Enter PIN: 5555
Registration completed!

Price list:
('1423', 7.88)
('1752', 4.99)
('2368', 5.25)
('2159', 0.99)
('2487', 12.52)
('4178', 8.00)
('5206', 4.25)
('6112', 5.77)
('6245', 4.88)
('6625', 2.99)
Enter 4-digit item code [or 9999 to stop]: 6112
Enter 4-digit item code [or 9999 to stop]: 9999
Item not found
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: probably because `readPriceList()` (that we don't get to see) is not converting data to integer when reading from file. so you're comparing strings with integers.

Comment: is price_list a list of tuples? or a dictionary? I think you need to look over how python data structures work

Comment: price_list is a dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the dictionary contains strings for keys, you don't need to convert anything to ints. I also moved the input to the bottom of the while loop so it doesn't show twice at the beginning.

```
def scanPrices():
    price_list = readPriceList()
    totalPrice = 0.0
    itemCode = input("Enter 4-digit item code [or 9999 to stop]: ")
    while itemCode != '9999':
        if itemCode in price_list:
            itemPrice = price_list[itemCode]
            print("Item found. Price:", itemPrice)
            totalPrice += itemPrice
        else:
            print("Item not found")
        itemCode = input("Enter 4-digit item code [or 9999 to stop]: ")
    return totalPrice
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing string with an integer, either convert the keys in the price_list dictionary to integer or don't convert the itemcode variable to integer, let it be string